# JSON: parsing with java and org.json (recursion)

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm using the package `org.json` to parse a JSONArray (I have the json strings saved in a database). However, I don't succeed in parsing it when the same key could have associated a String or a JSONObject, depending on the context.

For example, see the following JSON code...

```
[ { "cssClass" : "input_text",
    "required" : "undefined",
    "values" : "First Name"
  },
  { "cssClass" : "checkbox",
    "required" : "undefined",
    "title" : "What's on your pizza?",
    "values" : { "2" : { "baseline" : "undefined",
            "value" : "Extra Cheese"
          },
        "3" : { "baseline" : "undefined",
            "value" : "Pepperoni"
          }
      }
   }
]
```

In the code above, the key `"values"` has 2 possibilities...

1. A String with value `"First Name"`
2. A JSONObject with value `{"2":{"value":"Extra Cheese","baseline":"undefined"},"3":{"value":"Pepperoni","baseline":"undefined"}}`.

How am I able to process this correctly when the value could be 2 different data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably still need to detect whether it is a JSONObject or a String, so that you can process it further, but perhaps something here might help...

You could try something like this...

```
String cssClass = myJson.getString("cssClass");
if (cssClass.equals("input_text")){
    // Read it as a String
    String values = myJson.getString("values");
}
else if (cssClass.equals("checkbox")){
    // Read it as a JSONObject
    JSONObject values = myJson.JSONObject("values");
    // further processing here
}
```

Or maybe something like this...

```
String cssClass = myJson.getString("cssClass");
String values = myJson.getString("values");

if (cssClass.equals("input_text")){
    // do nothing - it's already a String
}
else if (cssClass.equals("checkbox")){
    // Parse the String into a JSONObject
    JSONObject valuesObject = new JSONObject(values);
    // further processing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it this way in js or java duplicate variable creation under same scope is invalid,so to avoid ambiguity put them in separate json object with different variable names before putting it to the json array.